# Вызов функции из строки

Tags: javascript

Есть строка:

> var s = 'function a(){...} function b(){...}'

Возможно ли из кода вызывать эти функции по отдельности, без разбиения на разные строки?

Comment: А как вы их сейчас вызываете?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Да, в данном случае если использовать eval

```
 var a = 'function f(){ alert(111); } function d(){ alert(222);}';
 eval(a);
 d();
```

Выведет алертом `222`. Но более безопасным считается следующий вид преобразования строки в функцию:

```
// function name and parameters to pass
var fnstring = "runMe";
var fnparams = ["aaa", "bbbb", "ccc"];

// find object
var fn = window[fnstring];

// is object a function?
if (typeof fn === "function") fn.apply(null, fnparams);
// как вариант:  if (typeof fn === "function") fn();

function runMe(a,b){
  alert(b);
}
```

Выведет алертом bbb

Код в исполнении здесь: http://plnkr.co/edit/OiQAVd9DMV2PfK0NG9vk

Answer (score 4):

У вас идет объявление ф-ции, а не их вызов

> var s = 'function a(){...} function b(){...}'

И даже если после этого вы напишете `eval(s);`, то ничего не произойдет, 
потому что ***вызова*** ***функций*** у вас нет нет.
Если писать самовызывающиеся ф-ции, как у вас, код вызовет ***ошибку***
 ( `;` нехватает между ф-циями ), а вот писать так можно

```
var s = "function a () { console.log('a'); }; function b () { console.log('b'); }; a(); b()");
eval(s);
```

Но `;` все равно необходимо ***расставлять***

Comment: `function a(){alert('a');} function b(){alert('b');}` работает без ;

Comment: @Джоффри, я же написал **самовызывающиеся**